# Ensure same results from multiple calls to a ref

Tags: module, ocaml, consistency

I call a function in a module to generate unique labels, eg.

```
MyMod.gensym
```

defined as

```
let gensym : string -> string =
  let c = ref 0 in
  fun s -> incr c; Printf.sprintf "!%s%d" s (!c)
```

But, I want to be able to get reproducible results at certain times from functions that use this gensym, eg.

```
let reproducible = SomeMod.call x
```

may return `["!a1"; "!a2"]` the first time and `["!a3"; ...]` the second

How can I ensure reproducible output in this case (eg. force ref to start from the same value), but without needing to change the implementation of gensym in its module?

Answer (score 1):

You could add an optional argument to reset it:

```ml
let gensym : ?reset:bool -> string -> string =
  let c = ref 0 in
  fun ?(reset=false) s ->
    if reset then
      c := 1
    else
      incr c;
    Printf.sprintf "!%s%d" s (!c)
```

Comment: thanks.  Sorry I wasn't clear -- I'm calling it from another module, so I can't change the actual gensym function -- I was hoping for just something like a forced reload or so

Comment: "forced reload"? Of the entire module? Can you change anything else about the module? If so, why can you not change this specific function?

Comment: my specific case -- generating compiler symbols -- it is hard to match output between successive runs and/or results in utop.  I **could** modify the module in theory, but I was more hoping for a way to run a clean start interactively in the repl, eg. a function `dump_ir "file"` so the gensyms in utop  match those generated by the native compiler